# Does anyone know why I'am getting error during amplify init ? I checked the memory is not full?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

ec2-user:~/environment/wild-rydes (master) $ amplify init 
Downloading release from https://d2bkhsss993doa.cloudfront.net/8.0.2/amplify-pkg-linux-x64.tgz
node:internal/buffer:959
super(bufferOrLength, byteOffset, length);
^

RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed
at new ArrayBuffer ()
at new Uint8Array ()
at new FastBuffer (node:internal/buffer:959:5)
at createUnsafeBuffer (node:internal/buffer:1062:12)
at allocate (node:buffer:410:10)
at Function.allocUnsafe (node:buffer:375:10)
at Function.concat (node:buffer:553:25)
at Extract. (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/binary.js:124:37)
at Extract.emit (node:events:538:35)
at finishMaybe (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:624:14)

Comment: Did you solve this yet? - having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be something related to **version 8.0.2**, which I'm sure AWS will fix at some point.

As a workaround you can install another Amplify CLI version and you will be able to use it.

Example:

```
npm i -g @aws-amplify/cli@7.6.21
```

Comment: I'm working through the AWS WildRydes walkthru on my own.  I tried various (more recent) versions to get it working and ended up corrupting my EC2 instance (which I had to destroy and start over).  If you already followed the step in the walkthru, do: `npm uninstall -g @aws-amplify/cli` then enter the command above from this answer and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Same error occured for version **8.1.0**

```
https://d2bkhsss993doa.cloudfront.net/8.1.0/amplify-pkg-linux-x64.tgz
```

Comment: And the same for 8.2.0 at https://d2bkhsss993doa.cloudfront.net/8.2.0/amplify-pkg-linux-x64.tgz

Comment: Same for 11.1 at https://package.cli.amplify.aws/11.1.0/amplify-pkg-linux-x64.tgz